# Continuous surjective from the unit interval to sphere 2

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Find a surjective continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow S^2$ where $S^2=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3: \Vert x \Vert=1\}$.

My attempt:

Define $g:[0,1] \rightarrow S^1$ by $g(x)=e^{2\pi xi}$. Then this function is clearly continuous and bijection, and homeomorphism. I am now looking for a continuous surjective $H:S^1 \rightarrow S^2$, if such a one exists and hence the problem solved by composition. So is there such a function $H$? If there is no one I would appreciate any help with that.

Comment: You're essentially looking for a _space-filling curve_.

Comment: I have not thought of that yet, can you tell me how to start with that?

Comment: There are such things.  I think it's possible.   Look it up.  There's a famous one by Peano.  Maybe it can be adapted, since it maps an interval onto a square,  or something.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=space+filling

Comment: Your function $g$ is not bijective and most certainly not a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: There exist space filling curves (i.e. continuous surjections) $[0,1] \to [0,1]^2$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve). Moreover, there exist continuous surjections $[0,1]^2 \to S^2$ ($[0,1]^2$ is isomorphic to $D^2$ and $D^2/S^1 \approx S^2$).

Comment: Can you state the function $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]^2?$

Comment: @Ahmed This is technically very complicated. See the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve and e.g. http://wwwmayr.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/konferenzen/Jass05/courses/2/Valgaerts/Valgaerts_paper.pdf . However, the existence of such curves belongs to "mathematical folklore". I doubt that it is really worth to understand the construction in all details. It suffices to get the **idea**.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot